# Best approach to grant web access to s3 directory

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to build a cms using a s3 bucket as a website.  I have a bucket policy that allows public/anonymous access to all but the /_admin directory.  To gain backend access I want the user to be able to provide a username/password that will change the bucket policy to allow /_admin access based on the users ip address.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

*I'm thinking of using the API Gateway to call a Lambda function that checks the username/password and then changes the policy.  A successful result will then redirect to the backend.

Comment: That seems like a pretty sketchy approach, to be honest.  Not the least of your concerns is the lack of guaranteed uniqueness of user to IP address on corporate and mobile networks, and the inability to avoid colliding updates since IAM policies may not have a consistency guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this by AWS best practices is to create an `IAM` role that will have permissions to access the `/_admin` directory. Using `Amazon Cognito` in `AWS SDK` for language of your choice you can retrieve the temporary credentials based on the role. You can then use the `AWS SDK` calls or you can adjust the `S3` bucket permissions to access your resource.

Comment: Using cognito was another option I looked at. Can you give some examples/links to the best practice for changing bucket permissions so that /_admin is accessible for the authenticated user? In other words, is there a better way than changing the bucket policy to allow the authenticated users ip address to access /_admin from the browser?

Comment: The problem is S3 is really just static - it doesn't let you do any logic. You can adjust the bucket policy for the IP address as you're proposing or you can use some custom header and have the policy check it.

Comment: That gives me some direction. Thanks.